# Passing parameters by value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

To all, I am learning Visual Basic and I am currently working on a Windows Application.  I have two text box methods (`usernameTextBox`, `passwordTextBox`).  In which the user will enter data and then hit the submit button (`Button1_Click`).  That method will call connect.  What I want to be able to do, is to have the user type-in their username and password. Then it is passed by value, not reference into `connect()` when it is invoked inside the Button method.

Kind of like an authentication page. Now I have values in `connect(FirstName:="JohnDoe", Password:="password")` - this is basically for testing MySQL server and for demonstration of what I am trying to attempt.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class SecurePasswordList
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Public Sub connect(ByVal FirstName As String, ByVal Password As String)
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "mysql"
        Dim server As String = "10.1.0.0"
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, FirstName, Password, DatabaseName)
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connect(FirstName:="JohnDoe", Password:="password")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SecurePasswordList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub usernameTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles usernameTextBox.TextChanged
        Dim FirstName As String
        FirstName = usernameTextBox.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub passwordTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles passwordTextBox.TextChanged
        Dim Password As String
        Password = passwordTextBox.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a case here. Your problem is syntactical error. It has really nothing to do with `ByVal/ByRef`. You already passing the values by value. Although, `string` is not a value type, therefore you only passing a value of the pointer to an object, to be precise. i.e. you don't copy string, you copy pointer.

Comment: You know that the code in your textchanged methods doesn't have any effect, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connect(FirstName:="JohnDoe", Password:="password")
End Sub
```

to

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connect(FirstName, Password)
End Sub
```

but you should ensure that FirstName and Password are initialized AND held as class variables.
Move

```
Dim FirstName As String
Dim FirstName As String
```

to be in the class, not the event handling functions (Click etc). Like this:

```
Public Class SecurePasswordList
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim FirstName As String
```

BUT really you can redo your code like this (as all you want is the Text from the controls):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class SecurePasswordList
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Public Sub connect(ByVal FirstName As String, ByVal Password As String)
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "mysql"
        Dim server As String = "10.1.0.0"
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, FirstName, Password, DatabaseName)
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connect(usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I dont think passing by value or reference is the issue here.  Do you want the connect function to modify the strings passed into it? I doubt it. So in that case Value or reference is fine.  Strings are passed by a copied instance by reference, so in effect they are passed by Value unless you use Byref in the function declaration which will.  Every class (int, string, etc) are passed differently in VB by default.  You need to check each type to know what it will do if you specify Byval or Byref. String creates a copy of the String if you use Byval, but is actually accessed using the pointer to the newly created String.  So it depends how deep you want to dig too

Comment: Grantly  -  This makes perfect sense! That's for your help all is good now.